# ruby 4 asset fetching fails on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, cdn, engineyard

Scenario: I'm uploading an image file to the server, when trying to access it, using curl, I'm getting it on every 2nd request.
e.g curl http://staging.muserver.com/system/assets/images/000/000/test.png

When i am getting 200ok, i can see that i am having ETag, when it fails i can see X-Request-Id and X-Runtime.

this error happen only on the amazon pre production, on local machine i cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Every other request sounds like you have a load balancer alternatively sending requests to a good or bad host, but without more details of your setup that's just a wild guess

Comment: requests are without lb, goes to the same place.....i am cruling to an image file....i know its there, and only every 2nd command i am getting 200ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frederick was right...i didn't setup LB...but engineyard supplied by default, when disabled, everything works fine.